# missing session data after clicking browser back button

Tags: php

I'm developing a simple member management system with `php`, and I've met a problem:

The user logs in and it is redirected to a main page and the user ID is saved in the session; there are some links to other pages in the main page, after the user clicks and is trying to go back to main by pressing browser "**Back**" button, sometimes the user ID in the session is lost.

I've checked the session save path, a new session file is created when I click "**Back**" button, so I assume the `session_start()` creates a new session for it; but I still don't know why, it's a random case...

Is there any way to solve it?

main.php:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
$echo_string = '
<body>
  <a href="a.php">a</a>
  <a href="b.php">b</a>
</body>';

if (!empty($_SESSION['user']))
  echo $echo_string;
else
  header("Location: login.php");
?>
```

login.php:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if (isset($_POST['userLogin'])) {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['userLogin'];
    // check userLogin in db
    ...
  }
  header("Location: main.php");
?>
<form novalidate="" method="post" action="login.php">
  <label class="hidden-label" for="Username">Username</label>
  <input id="Username" name="userLogin" type="text" placeholder="Username" value="" spellcheck="false" class="">
  <label class="hidden-label" for="Passwd">Password</label>
  <input id="Passwd" name="userPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="">
  <input id="signIn" name="signIn" class="rc-button rc-button-submit" type="submit" value="Log in">
</form>
```

a.php:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>...</head>
  <?php
    $echo_string = '...'; // a html format string
    if (!empty($_SESSION['user']))
      echo $echo_string;
    else
      header("Location: login.php");
  ?>
</html>
```

b.php is almost same as a.php

Thanks.

BR,
Sean

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: sorry, a newbie in this forum, code posted

Answer (score -1):

`session_start()`-docs:
"`session_start()` creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie."

so you see, that when a session exists it doesnt create a new, that means when you set something like `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;` you should check before if `$_SESSION` is already filled with your infos